# Solution to $y′=x+y,\, y(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to learn numerical method for differentials. It is key for me to understand this stuff right now, but I've come across an obstacle.

The books I read about these all seem to often say '*exact solution is easily found to be*' in more or less the same way. I clearly have an issue with this, because I do not know any practical method, or even the name of the method I am suppose to learn, to find this sort of solution 'easily' or sometimes at all.

> We shall illustrate our methods by applying them to the simple problem
> $y′=x+y, y(0)=1, (3)$ which we call our benchmark problem. This
> differential equation in $(3)$ is clearly linear, and the exact solution
> is easily found to be $y=2e^x − x − 1$.

I look at this, and I don't understand. I guess I can say I covered one of these ideas which is that $y'=y, y(0) = 1$ because it is glearingly obvious that the only thing that differentiates to itself is $e^x$.

Now, $y' = x+y$, how would I approach that? What is the method behind the solution to get there? I tried to look at the solution instead, but $y'$ of the solution for me is $2e^x - 1$.

This must be something really trivial, but I just don't get it.

Comment: I changed the tag from [tag:numerical-calculus] to [tag:ordinary-differential-equations], because I think you're asking for an exact solution to $y'-y=x$, not a numerical approximation, here

Comment: You should probably take a step back and learn a little bit about elementary differential equations, using a book such as Boyce and DiPrima. If you don't want to do that, one standard method for solving this problem is the method of integrating factors. Another is to use superposition, i.e. add a particular solution and a homogeneous solution together, in which case you need to figure out a particular solution. In this case you can guess that the solution is a linear function (since $y \mapsto y'-y$ turns linear functions into linear functions) and then find the coefficients.

Comment: [Use an integrating factor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations)

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial... when you know the theory of differential equations. I will lead you to a solution by an ad-hoc trial and error process.

You correctly observe that $(e^x)'=e^x$. If we plug this tentative solution in the equation, we have

$$e^x\color{red}=x+e^x$$ which is not what we want because of the term $x$. So let us try $y=e^x-x$, and we get

$$e^x-1\color{red}=e^x.$$ Then to get rid of the $1$, $y=e^x-x-1$, and

$$e^x-1=e^x-1.$$

But we are not done yet, because of the condition $y(0)=1$, while our solution says $y(0)=0$. But recall that $(e^x)'=e^x$, so that we can freely add terms $e^x$ without violating the equation. As we are off by one unit and $e^0=1$, the fix is

$$y=e^x+e^x-x-1.$$

---

The real way would be:

- characterize the equation as first order linear with constant coefficients.
- solve the "homogeneous" part of the equation, $y'-y=0$, giving $y=ce^x$ for some $c$;
- find any solution of the initial equation, $y'-y=x$. As the RHS is a linear polynomial, we can try a linear polynomial, let $ax+b$. Then $a-ax-b=x$ yields $y=-x-1$.
- combine these two solutions $y=ce^x-x-1$ and solve for $c$ after plugging the condition $y(0)=1$, which gives $c=2$.

Answer (score 1):

I solve

$y' = y + x, \; y(0) = 1 \tag 1$

in another "real way", as follows: write the equation as

$y' - y  = x; \tag 2$

make the clever observation that

$(e^{-x}y)' = -e^{-x}y + e^{-x}y'$
$= e^{-x}y' - e^{-x}y = e^{-x}(y' - y); \tag 3$

in light of (2) this becomes

$(e^{-x}y)' = xe^{-x}; \tag 4$

integrate 'twixt $0$ and any value of $x$:

$e^{-x}y(x) - y(0) = \displaystyle \int_0^x (e^{-u}y(u))'  \; du = \int_0^x ue^{-u} \; du; \tag 5$

the right-hand integral may be integrated by parts to yield

$\displaystyle \int_0^x ue^{-u} \; du = -(x + 1)e^{-x} + 1; \tag 6$

substituting this and the initial condition $y(0) = 1$ into (5):

$e^{-x}y(x) - 1 = -(x + 1)e^{-x} + 1, \tag 7$

or

$y(x) = 2e^x - x - 1. \tag 8$

***Check:***

from (8),

$y' = 2e^x - 1, \tag 9$

$y'- y = x, \tag{10}$

$y' = y + x, \tag{11}$

$y(0) = 1; \tag{12}$

(11) and (12) together are (1). $ \checkmark$

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve $$y'=y+x$$ Let $y=z-x$ to make
$$z'-1=z\implies z'-z=1$$ Now, the homogeneous solution is $z=c e^{x}$. Use now the variation of parameter to get
$$c' \,e^{x}=1 \implies c'=e^{-x}\implies c=-e^{-x}+k\implies z=-1+ke^{x} $$ Back to $y$
$$y=-x-1+ke^{x}$$ and using the condition $k=2$
$$y=2e^{x}-x-1$$